# Pass value from one form to another without reloading

Tags: c#, wpf

how can i pass values from one window to another window with out reloading the window

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(lbl_date1.Content);

    Vazhipadu_receipt obj = new Vazhipadu_receipt(date);
    obj.ShowDialog();
    //this.Close();

}

public Vazhipadu_receipt(DateTime date)
{
    //DateTime date_v = date;
    //string day = date_v.ToString("dd");

    //txt_mnth_v.Text = date.ToString("MM");
    //txt_year_v.Text = date.ToString("yyyy");
    InitializeComponent();
    //window_load();
    load();
    txt_day_v.Text = date.ToString("dd");
    txt_mnth_v.Text = date.ToString("MM");
    txt_year_v.Text = date.ToString("yyyy");
   // this.sessionNow = sessionNow;
}
```

Comment: Glad to see some function name in my mother tongue. Please make your question more clear so that we could understand it.

Comment: Use proper data binding. That is the advantage of WPF over traditional Windows Forms. Data binding allows you to update the UI without reloading as soon as the property value changes. Google for relevant tutorials.

Comment: @kalidas what u have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use MVVM pattern its not required the reloading the controls
and if you want to pass data from one page to another after loading the new window you need to used Delegates,Event,Actions for same there are lots of options are available in WPF/C#

I am considering the you have one main page and from there you are trying to open new window (Vazhipadu_receipt)

in this case you need to follow the following steps
First create the Delegate and Event like following

```
public delegate void ChildControlDelegate(bool IsVisible);//Delegate with Parameter which value you need to pass


public event ChildControlDelegate GetDataFromChild;//Event to execute
```

then raise event when you need to pass value like below

```
if (GetDataFromChild != null)
        {
            GetDataFromChild(true);
        }
```

then in another page you need to register the event like below

```
usrcntrleStatement obj = new usrcntrleStatement(pnsnLoginmodel);
obj.GetDataFromChild += Obj_GetDataFromChild;
```

and create new Method for value capturing

```
private void Obj_GetDataFromChild(bool IsVisible)
    {
        if (IsVisible)
            LoadingGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else 
            LoadingGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```